# Changing css dynamically wth php

Tags: javascript, php

Hi guys I am developing a website using materialize css framework and php  for the back end part. 
When I log in on the website I want change the class of the login button, so it is no longer visible. And the class of a log out button so it can be visible. 
Here is my code where I start  a session at the top of index.php

```
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js"
            integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Travelville</title>
    <?php
        include 'members_dB.php';
        session_start();
    ?>
```

Here is my code. index.php: where I want the buttons are.

```
<ul class = "right hide-on-med-and-down"> <!--Will hide on-med..-->
<li>
    <div class ="input-field">
        <input type="text" class ="white grey-text autocomplete"
        id ="autocomplete-input" placeholder="Aruba, Cancun, etc.."
         >
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <?php
    //session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])){
            $class = 'class="waves-effect waves-light btn scale-transition scale-out"';
            $classL = 'class="waves-effect waves-light btn scale-transition"';
    } else {
            $class = 'class="waves-effect waves-light btn scale-transition"';
            $classL = 'class="waves-effect waves-light btn scale-transition scale-out"';
    }
    ?>
    <a  href = "#login" id = "login"
    <?php  echo $class ?> >
        <span>Log in </span>
    <i class="large material-icons right">computer</i></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a  href = "cart.php"
    class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
        <span>Cart </span>
    <i class="large material-icons right">shopping_cart</i></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a  href = "#" id = "logout"
    <?php  echo $classL ?> >
        <span>Log Out </span>
    <i class="large material-icons right">computer</i></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

login.php: where the login form is being displayed:

```
<!--Log in section-->
<section id ="login" class ="section section-popular scrollspy">
<div class ="container">
<div class="row">
<?php
check_login();
if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user'])) {

        echo '<p>You are logged in as: '.$_SESSION['valid_user'].' <br />';                                                                                                      echo '<a href="logout.php">Log out</a></p>';
} else {
    if (isset($userid))  {
        // if they've tried and failed to log in
        echo '<p>Could not log you in.</p>';
    } else {
        they have not tried to log in yet or have logged out
        echo '<p>You are not logged in.</p>';
    }
    echo '<form  class="col s12"  action="index.php" method="post">';
    echo '<div  class="row">';
    echo '<div class="input-field col s12">';
            echo '<input placeholder="Username" id="username"
            name = "username" type="text" class="validate">';
            echo '<label for="first_name">First Name</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="input-field col s12">';
        echo '<input placeholder = "Password" id = "password"
            name = "password" type="password" class="validate">';
        echo '<label for="password">Password</label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    //<!--<button type="submit" name="login" id = "button">Login</button> -->
    echo '<input id = "login" type ="submit" value ="Login"
            id="refresh"
    class="btn">';
    echo '<input id = "show" type ="submit" value ="Sign up" class =
                    "waves-effect waves-light btn scale-transition scale-out">';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Here is members_db.php which contains check_login():

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
function check_login(){
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        // if the user has just tried to log in
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $db_conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'trav_dB');

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'Connection to database failed:'.mysqli_connect_error();
            exit();
        }
        $query = "SELECT *FROM `customers` WHERE   username='".$username."' AND   password = '".$password."'  ";
        $result = $db_conn->query($query);
        if ($result->num_rows) {
            // if they are in the database register the user id
            $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
        }
        $db_conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

After I hit submit, and successfully get access to the database the page reloads, but the class of `<a href ="#" id = "login" ..` of login does not update. Until I reload the page again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to learn AJAX. Just a comment. Why not have the CSS already made, then just add a JavaScript `element.className`?

Comment: I suggest that you use JavaScript for this.

Comment: @StackSlave I am not familiar with AJAX. How would I accomplish what I am trying to do with AJAX, would AJAX replace php? Can I still use materialize frame work with AJAZ?

Comment: You should read about sql injection and storing plain passwords (both of which you are doing).

Comment: I would use prepared statements.